# Keras - Choosing the right batch / epoch size for a seq2seq problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, seq2seq

Based on [this repository](https://github.com/LukeTonin/keras-seq-2-seq-signal-prediction) (Keras implementation of a sequence to sequence model for time series prediction) I've built an encoder-decoder model to predict a sensor signal.

My Dataset is comprised of 439 batches of 61 samples each with 20 features. Each batch is 61 days of sensor data as seen in the figure below:

[image]

Since unlike the repository, my dataset is of multiple signals and not one continues signal
What should be optimal batch_size and epochs to start with? Should the batch_size be 61 as the size of the batches?

Comment: if I understood correctly, the input of your enc-dec is (n_samples, 61, 20)

Comment: you are correct, that is right

Comment: ok, a batch_size of 61 (61,61,20) doesn't seem to have any special meaning (in my opinion). what I can suggest is to start using low batch dim and then increase step by step and check performances... to do all these trials you need to have a good validation strategy

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what validation strategy would you recommend?

Comment: your it's a time series problem (I don't know details) so take care to maintain the temporal dependencies when you operate train/valid splitting. in problem with few data, apply a cross valid procedure may be very important